# Shell script with EXPECT and PUT to SFTP server

Tags: backup, sftp, expect

I'm working on a shell script and I'm trying to send a backup file to a sftp server :

```
remotepath=/backup/
expect -c "
spawn sftp user@172.11.23.4
expect "password:"
send "password123\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /back_up/bkp_2022.tar.gz $remotepath\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
"
```

And this is the output that I get without the file being transfer - It just creates "?send put" and "?send byer?".

```
-rw-r-----. 1 admin admin 1267 Aug 17 11:14 script.sh
-rw-r-----. 1 admin admin    0 Aug 17 11:15 ?send put
-rw-r-----. 1 admin admin  167 Aug 17 11:15 ?send byer?
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: Could you use `scp` instead of `sftp`?

Comment: If the transfer can take more than 10 seconds, add `set timeout -1` to the top of the expect code.

Answer (score 1):

either escape inner quote (`"`), or use here doc syntax

```
remotepath=/backup/
expect <<EOF
spawn sftp user@172.11.23.4
expect "password:"
send "password123\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /back_up/bkp_2022.tar.gz $remotepath\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

please note that I didn't test